# What is the IntelliJ shortcuts used with mouse click?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I am new in IntelliJ (use v2021.1) and just learn several shortcuts and use them. However, I realized some shortcuts that can be used with mouse click as shown below:

Ctrl + Click

Alt + Click

I think they have multiple purposes e.g. go to definition, find usages. But I want to learn what their usages exactly?

And is there similar useful shortcuts that can be used with mouse click in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It's possibl to open "Settings | Keymap", click on "Find Actions by Shortcut" button and check actions per shortcut.

Comment: Perfect!.. Thanks a lot, it is really very useful tips.